# StreamPlot is not working

Tags: plotting

After finding the gradient of the scalar field F(x,y)= (x^2 * y^2) + (y^2 * z^2) + (x^2 * z^2) I am trying to get its direction field with StreamPlot which is showing an empty box. I did:

```
v = Grad[F[x, y], {x, y, z}]
{2xy^2 + 2xz^2, 2x^2y + 2yz^2, 2x^2z + 2y^2z}

direcplot = 
 StreamPlot[{2xy^2 + 2xz^2, 2x^2y + 2yz^2, 2x^2z + 2y^2z}, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}]
```

But this does not show the direction fields. What went wrong?

Comment: (1) `xy` is not `x y`: the space denotes multiplication.  Otherwise `xy` is a single variable, distinct from either `x` or `y`. (2) `StreamPlot` works for 2D vector fields only.  There is no 3D equivalent. The closest thing is `VectorPlot3D`.

Comment: I tried VectorPlot3D which worked. I will go with that for showing direction fields in this case. Also, your explanation clarified why StreamPlot wasn't working in case of v here.

Comment: Yeah, it really should check the vector field for dimension and numerical evaluation and emit errors.  If you feel like complaining to WRI, you can give feedback under the Help menu.  Eventually they might get around to adding those checks.